# Why does increasing work function decrease quantum yield?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider a light source incident on a metal plate and the photoelectrons are collected by a plate of varying potential difference with respect to the metal plate. My notes say that when the work function of the metal is increased (i.e. changing the metal plate), the photoelectric yield decreases and hence the maximum photoelectric current decreases (where the photoelectric yield is the ratio of photoelectron emission to photon incidence).

Assuming the frequency of the light source is above the threshold frequency for both metals, the energy of a photon goes into liberating an electron and the remaining energy is converted into the kinetic energy of the photoelectron
$$
hf = \phi + \dfrac{1}{2}m_e v_e^2
$$

By my understanding, the increase in the work function would mean the resulting kinetic energy of the electrons would fall on average, so the stopping potential would decrease as a lesser negative potential is required to ensure the most energetic photon does not reach the collecting plate. However, shouldn't the rate of photoelectron emission not change, considering that the energy of each photon did not change so the yield of photoelectrons should still remain constant. So when the plate is made sufficiently positive such that all photoelectrons that are emitted are attracted into the collecting plate, the maximum photoelectric current should still be the same. Where is there a flaw in my reasoning?